# Google Could SQL Cannot connect to DB with new user

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to install WordPress on Google's App Engine for PHP with Cloud SQL.  However, I can't give my WP database user access to their DB.

Looking at the users in my Cloud SQL instance, the grant privilege for the root@% account is unchecked.  However, in their WP setup doc, they say to use GRANT ALL for the new database user.  See step 6 at:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

Subsequently, I cannot give rights to the new WordPress DB to the user account for the app.  Anyone know what they expect us to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that you have to go through a few steps in the cloud console to execute SQL statements as root@localhost.

Create a .sql file (flat text) and upload it to a cloud storage "bucket" (a directory basically), the filename must contain .sql as it's extension.  Then you return to the cloud sql instance and choose import.  Import the sql file via a special path of gs://[bucket name]/[filename].sql It automatically recognizes your gs (Cloud Storage) path.

*This was briefly mentioned in the setup documentation, however was very vague in where the sql file was uploaded and how to reference it's path.*

It will import the commands, you can verify its success via the operations screen.  I did try granting root@% the global grant privilege via the mysql user's table by setting its Grant_priv field to 'Y' but I still receive access denied when trying to grant privileges via SQLyog.  At least I have a workaround.