# Grant Users on Google CloudSQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have create a CloudSQL instance in Google Cloud.

I requested an IP and I connect to the mySql instace from my network. I use the root user and it works right.

The problem is when I create a new user, I create it correctly but I cannot grant permissions to it.

I have tried:

`GRANT  CREATE ON  global.* TO 'admin'@'127.0.0.1'`

And I always receive:

`Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'global'`

I have seen that the user root@localhost has privileges for grant, but not the user root@%.

Thank you.

Comment: See my answer at:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757261/google-could-sql-cannot-connect-to-db-with-new-user?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You managed to hit a bug. A workaround is to connect to the instance and run the following:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y' WHERE host = '%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After that, disconnect and connect again. The GRANT should work properly now.